# Adding JS to theme

Tags: magento2, theme, requirejs

I've seen a few similar posts on the Magento SE but none seem to work for me. I'm probably missing something but I for whatever reason my JS is not being included. I have a theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/default

Inside is the file tree:

```
|-composer.json
|-etc/
|-Magento_Catalog/
|-media/
|-registration.php
|-requirejs-config.js
|-theme.xml
|-web/
```

Inside my `requirejs-config.js` file is this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            themejs: 'js/main'
        }
    }
};
```

and my `web/js/main.js` file:

```
define(['jquery'], function($)
{
    "use strict";

    return function themejs()
    {
        alert('hello world');
    }
});
```

I then run:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
$ php bin/magento cache:clean
```

I refresh my page but no alert is seen. I then do a find in the console tab and can't see my newly added .js file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     var config = {
                 paths: {
                themejs:        'js/main'
            },
            shim: {
                themejs: {
                    deps: ['jquery']
                }
            }

        };


define([
  "jquery",
  "whatever lib you wanna use..."
], 
function($) {
  "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function($){
        console.log("DID IT! jQuery log complete.");
    });
    return;
});
```

Comment: why do I need owlcarousel? Or is this a suggested way of writing?

Comment: yes, you can change as you want

Comment: if it solve your problem please tick answer

Comment: It does not I'm afraid :/

Comment: I edit so you can copy

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Send me code how you calling this file

Comment: what do you mean calling the file? all of my theme code for JS is in the OP ?